# Get size of dask array without eager loading it

Tags: python, numpy, dask

With certain processes, dask does not know the output array size/shape a priori. Is there a way to access this value without computing the entire array in memory?
See for instance:

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

arr = da.random.randint(1, 5, size=(5000,5000),
                        dtype=np.uint8, chunks=(1000,1000))
y, x = da.where(arr == 2)
print(y.size) # nan
y = y.compute()
print(y.size) # OK
```

How can I get the size of `y` without running `compute()` on the whole array?

Comment: in general, no. if the size of the array is a result of the operation, then the shape can't be known and dask can't report it until you compute the result. did you have a specific case in mind that you think *should* be known but dask doesn't know the shape?

Comment: unless you're asking if there's a way to do (redundant) work in order to evaluate the shape?

Comment: Thing is it's not a *result* from a function but an array attribute. I can get `da.sum(y).compute()` in a memory friendly way for instance, but can't find a way to get attribute values in a similar memory friendly way. `da.sum(da.ones_like(y)).compute()` appears to not work either

Comment: Apparently the `compute_chunk_sizes()` method does the trick and is a bit more memory friendly than evaluating the full `y` array

Comment: nice! yeah I think that's the answer :)